# Videos block each other while loading on the same page in Electron App (using video.js)

Tags: javascript, video, electron, video.js

Following code loads the videos but both players are ready at the same time.
When one video is smaller it won't be ready until the second video is ready too.

I have two video Tags on the same html page:

```
<video id="player1" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" autoplay data-setup='{}'>
     <source src="" </source>
</video>

<video id="player2" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" autoplay data-setup='{}'>
     <source src="" </source>
</video>
```

and try to load different sources into them with this function:

```
function loadVid(playerId, vidSrc, callback) {
    var player = videojs(playerId);
    player.src(vidSrc);
    player.load();
    player.play();
    callback();
}
```

which I call in a click event:

```
loadVideoBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    loadVid("player1", "pathTo/video1.mp4", function() {});
    loadVid("player2", "pathTo/video2.mp4", function() {});
}
```

Changing the played videos dynamically is making things even worse as they sometimes load, start playing, stop for a second and then start playing again, all in sync.

Can someone point me to whatever I am missing or misunderstanding?